# new field false in Package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

After upgrading to `npm 5.*` I have noticed a new field on the `package.json` which is really obscure and unintelligible.

What **`false: {}`** means?

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {},

  // What that means? What's the goal?
  "false": {}
}
```

Comment: Github issue is open for this, here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was bug [#17141](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17141) in npm.

It was fixed in commit [c3b586a](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/c3b586aafa9eabac572eb6e2b8a7266536dbc65b) on June 30th and that was released in [version 5.1.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.1.0) on July 5th.

The fix for anyone experiencing this is to simply update npm.

You can update by running: `npm install -g npm`