# What is the npm's "false" option in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I noticed recently that npm sets a `"false" : {}` field in package.json after `npm prune` and `npm update`.

What is its purpose?

There is no such option in the npm manual https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config

The environment is nodejs v 8.1.3 and npm v 5.0.1 under Ubuntu 17.04 and Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: I've never seen it, does it set it on its own?

Comment: Yes it is. I noticed it yesterday when updating packages on my laptop and deleted it. Today I pulled the changes on my workstation and after `npm prune` and `npm update` I noticed it again at the bottom of the `package.json` .

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that now.

Comment: There's a Github [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17141) open for this.

Comment: Also, the same question has been asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564024/new-field-false-in-package-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new field false in Package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564024/new-field-false-in-package-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was bug and you can find fix for this here in [new release](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.1.0).

Here is [fix commit](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/c3b586aafa9eabac572eb6e2b8a7266536dbc65b).